# How to set to tag width and height of included image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of blocks `div.project` and each block includes image with different width and height. I need to set width and height of image to `div.project`.

```
 $('.project').find('img').each(function() {
        var width = $('img').width();
        var height = $('img').height();
       $('.project').css('width',width);
        $('.project').css('height',height);
      });
```

The problem is jquery set width and height of first `div.project` to each `div.project`.

Answer (score 1):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/44t0aw9d/

> **NOTE:**  You have to use this keyword in your each loop because if you point to
>   .project class then last image of width and height will apply to .project
>   class

```
$('.project').find('img').each(function () {
     console.log($(this))
     var width = $(this).width();
     var height = $(this).height();
     console.log($($(this).parentElement))
     if ($(this)[0].parentElement) {
         $($(this)[0].parentElement).css('width', width);
         $($(this)[0].parentElement).css('height', height);

     }
 });
```

And insted of **parentElement** you can use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) also

```
 $('.project').find('img').each(function () {
     var width = $(this).width();
     var height = $(this).height();
     $(this).parent().css('width', width);
     $(this).parent().css('height', height);

 });
```

**EDIT**

This is one more solution. http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/44t0aw9d/2/
, And I think this solution is good because from paren will fing **img** tag so it is efficient then above two solutions.

```
 $('.project').each(function () {
     $img = $(this).find('img')
     var width = $img.width();
     var height = $img.height();
     $(this).css('width', width);
     $(this).css('height', height);

 });
```

Comment: I would use `closest('.project')` instead of `parent` as the img might not be the direct child (as op has used `.find` instead of `.children`)

Comment: i edited my answer as @Pete said **img might not be the direct child** so i am accessing child from parent now.